# How to mimic the use of sequences (from Oracle) using SQL Server and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, sequences

We have always enjoyed the use of a sequence in Oracle databases in order to create globally-unique primary key IDs across an entire database. So much, that we will mimic the same thing when using SQL Server databases:

```
CREATE TABLE MainSequence(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) CONSTRAINT pkMainSequence PRIMARY KEY
)
```

I'm trying to switch over to Entity Framework, which is very new to me. It seemed like it would be trivial to create an extension method that I could use to quickly get the next available globally-unique Id.

```
public static int GetNextId( this Entities db ) {
    var ms = new MainSequence();
    db.MainSequences.AddObject( ms );
    db.SaveChanges( SaveOptions.None );
    return ms.Id;
}
```

Since it's an identity column, all I should have to do is add a new object to the database and save the changes so that the Id property is updated with a real value. This works fine. But I seem to run into trouble when trying to use it for foreign-key-related tables:

```
var dataId = db.GetNextId();
db.Datas.AddObject( Data.CreateData( dataId, someValueForThisColumn );
db.Caches.AddObject( 
                    Cache.CreateCache( db.GetNextId(),
                    DatabaseMethods.GetOrAddLocation( source.GetLocationText() ),
                    DateTime.Now,
                    dataId ) );
```

The Cache table has a foreign key to the Data table. When `SaveChanges();` is called immediately after this, an exception is generated.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pkData'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Data'. The duplicate key value is (78162).
>   The statement has been terminated.

For some reason it appears the new data row is trying to get inserted into the database twice, though I'm not sure why that would be. I've confirmed that for every time the code is run, a different MainSequence ID is returned. It seems as though calling `db.SaveChanges` whenever a new ID is obtained is the problem, but there's no other way that can get populated with a real `int` and I don't see why it would be a problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Either wait for SQL Server 2012 (which will have full support for the `SEQUENCE` db object), or then use the `IDENTITY` column specifier to let SQL Server automatically dish out sequential ID's for your table - don't replicate this manually, that's a disaster waiting to happen....

Comment: We've been replicating the use of Sequences with SQL Server for years without a problem not using Entity Framework. Despite the title of my question, I don't really believe the problem has anything to do with replicating a Sequence. It seems like the problem I'm having is a misunderstanding of the `SaveChanges(SaveOption)` method where either I'm not allowed to call it several times, or need to do it in some other way.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you try to test it with a fixed value assigned to `dataId` (`var dataId = 12345`)

Comment: What do you enjoy about them - the fact they're globally unique?  If that's it why not generate sequential guids?

Comment: @WiktorZychla - Yes. (I'm not just making an assumption, I did just try it.)

Comment: @JamesGaunt I enjoy that they're globally unique. They can reduce confusion when debugging a situation with multiple tables- no Id will be the same in any other record in the entire database. The reason I need it this way is to maintain compatibility with our framework: whose goal is to maintain transparency of the underlying database provider: Oracle vs SQL Server. Plus, "I couldn't figure out how to get it work" isn't a good enough reason to change our method of doing things.

Comment: @Sam.Rueby on the other hand, I don't think it's wise to *always* adopt the opinion that the way you're trying to do things is the right way. I'm not saying for this case, but in general if something is hard to do there might be a reason - and an easier solution doesn't make it inferior, especially if it still accomplishes all of your goals.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - True! And if you had said for this case: I'm not yet convinced that what I'm attempting to do is hard (it sure sounds trivial, and we have no problem doing it with old ADO.NET methods) so to immediately dump an idea and attempt a method that is already understood would be like developing complex custom methods to turn any type into a string and back, before doing some research and learning that all you had to do was slap an attribute on the type and use a .NET-provided serialization object.

Comment: @Sam.Rueby - I would have to question how transparent your framework is if it depends on a feature that's only avaialable in Oracle.  I would suggest that your framework needs to change to abstract this portion so that it can be done in different ways depending on the database.  The correct answer to tell your bosses is "This feature isn't database agnostic"

Comment: Apparently I doomed the constructiveness of this question with the title, since we're focusing on what I desire and not the actual issue, which was a misunderstanding of `SaveOptions`.

Comment: @MystereMan The point of the framework is to abstract the idea of "get me a unique id". It _does_ do it in different ways based on the database, which is the point: Oracle has Sequences and SQL Server has the ability to provide something _very_ similar: a table with a single Identity column. Whatever products utilizing the framework has the ability to to be deployed on servers utilizing different underlying databases. I didn't mean to say "to maintain the compatibility of the framework". I intended to say that the framework itself needs the changing, not what is using it.

Comment: @Sam.Rueby - Typically, one does not need to do what you're doing with EF.  You simply join up the objects in the framework, and it takes care of assigning keys during the save operation.  Thus, you don't have to get the key so you can assign it elsewhere.  If your framework requires that you do it that way, i'd suggest that maybe EF is not the right tool to be using underneat it, and maybe just do things as straight ADO.NET

Comment: I agree there is a conflict here between using EF and wanting to mimic the behaviour of a different system. Personally I think EF and other such frameworks are a solution looking for a problem, and once adopted tend to throw up myriad problems looking for solutions - hence your question. Take control of your data access layer, implement it how you like it, and break free of EF constraints or paradigms.

Comment: @Gaunt, there are are days when I agree with you.  I've worked with NHibernate, EF, and now DevExpress' XPO.  They're great and certainly do abstract all lot of ORM details from a developer but what if, for example, you're writing a web app where most CRUD work is fairly stateless and there's minimal caching needed? Furthermore, let's say the backend DB will always be the same technology. What's the value proposition?  I'm a big fan of TDD and DDD and maybe those have some of the best arguments but there are some days when I just want to crawl back to simple ADO and be done with it!

Answer (score 1):

My problem is the line `db.SaveChanges( SaveOptions.None );`. My reason for using this option was to avoid SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave, which in my mind, through information gathered from other StackOverflow questions (either invalid or misunderstood) I thought would provide me a basic form of database transaction. I did read the MSDN documentation several times:

> After changes are saved, the AcceptAllChangesAfterSave() method is called, which resets change tracking in the ObjectStateManager.

That to me sounds an awful like transaction-change-tracking. I thought that if the changes were not accepted on a save call that the database "transaction" would be rolled back in the case of an error (I later found out this wasn't the case). Instead, all this does is make the ObjectContext still consider the change to be unsaved. So upon the next save call, the "unsaved" changes would be re-applied. Ta-da, primary key exception.This also explains why my main sequence was skipping values.

Comment: yes indeed, try to stay away from passing around the context, create it, make your changes and then fire ONE save changes call. As soon as you do something that leads you to thinking about manipulating the change state of the entities you're asking for trouble